# How to write a program that prints the range of -num1 to -num2 and stops when -num1 is a factor of num2?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I was able to write a program that prints the range of num1 to num2 but the problem is when a negative number is entered, it ignores the condition that has entered inside the loop.

For instance, if num1 = -10 and num2 = -1, its supposed to print -10 to -5 only since -10 % -5 == 0. But it prints -10 to -1 instead and ignores the if condition.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter starting: ");
        start = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter ending: ");
        end = input.nextInt();
        
        while(start <= end){
            System.out.println(start);
            start++;

            if(end%start == 0){
                System.out.println(start);
                break;
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

It follows the condition if both numbers are positive but ignores the condition if both negative. I want it to function the same regardless of the number sign.

Comment: It looks like end is supposed to go down instead of start going up.

Comment: Yes. From the lowest to the highest. Basically I wanted to print the range of numbers between starting point and ending point and stop the loop once the next printed number is a factor to the end point. Also, I think another issue is the zero. 0%number isn't correct so stops automatically in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code - `num_1 = -10` and `num_2 = -1`. And how can it print -10 to -5 first of all?

Look at your If the condition which means `num_2 % num_1 == 0` that will never be true in that case that's why it is printing `-10 to -1`.

Can you elaborate more or give me a particular test case so that I can look for the correct code? I think your code is correct just check with the right test scenarios.

Comment: Yeah you're right. It's a flaw in logic of the code. Basically what I want to happen is that I want to print the range of a given number with starting point num1 and end point num2. For instance, starting point is 1 and end point is 10. So print the numbers between 1 and 10 but once the next printed number is a factor of the end point, the loop stops. Also, is it possible that if the inputted or next number is zero, can it be ignored and can still continue with the loop?